# Creating draggable and droppable iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, drag-and-drop

How can we create iframes that are draggable and droppable? I have a panel consisting of 4 iframes. I would want to drag an iframe over another, and at drop operation iframes should swap positions. For instance, dragging iframe 1 over iframe 2, should result in iframe 2 getting displayed in the space previously occupied by iframe 1. Any pointers on how do I go about implementing this functionality? I am clueless on how to associate drag-drop events with iframes.

Comment: Couldn't you just make the iframe container element (a `<div>`, for example) a draggable target?

Comment: This is something I am looking into. It looks complex, but thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I'd recommend using `div` elements instead of `iframe`. Iframes generally contain individual HTML pages, so it's going to be really difficult to get them to interact they way you're looking for. Try checking out jQuery UI's droppable action. http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: I had once tried to use object element inside div to host webpages, but it was giving the same problem as iframes, which is events happening on webpages not getting propagated up to the parent div, unless I overlay a transparent div over the object element. So I decided to let go the idea of hosting webpage inside a div, and stuck to iframes. Anyways thanks for your comment ! :)

Comment: This is not always possible to load the iframe content in the parent document. As for example, if you have an inline editor/ code editor inside div and you place an unclosed style tag.. the whole application will blow up if that gets saved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with simple drag and drop using iframes and jquery ui. on this article

[jquery ui How to get a id of a draggable item when i click on the droppable item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643112/jquery-ui-how-to-get-a-id-of-a-draggable-item-when-i-click-on-the-droppable-item)

it has something to to with:

`var itemId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
 $(this).data('dropped', itemId);`

I also tweaked it a bit. hope this helps! enjoy

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/hB9xHZmCwDYfS3VxPWgt?p=preview
```