# jquery ui How to get a id of a draggable item when i click on the droppable item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

i've tried for several days and i can't get it work.
I want to get the id of div (`ui-widget-content`) that is the draggable item, when i dropped and click on the div (`ui-widget-header`) that is the dropped item but i can't get it work.

```
      <script>

         $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#j1, #j2, #j3, #j4, #j5, #j6").draggable();
            $("#p1, #p2, #p3, #p4, #p5, #p6").droppable({
               hoverClass: 'ui-state-hover',
               helper: 'clone',
               cursor: 'move',
               drop: function (event, ui) {
                  $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
                  $(ui.draggable).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
                  $(ui.draggable).draggable('enable');
                  console.log('Dragged: ' + alert(ui.draggable.attr("id")));
               }
            });
         });

         $('ui-widget-header').click(function () {
             var item_id = ui.item.attr('id');
         });
         alert('item_id');
         //$('.ui-droppable').click(function(){
         //    var myStringPosition = $('div'); // $(event.target).attr('id');
         //    $('.ui-droppable').each(function(){
         //      myStringPosition = $(this)[0].id; 
         //    });
         //    alert(myStringPosition);
         //});

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>

      <div id="j1" class="ui-widget-content" data-userid="1">Jogador 1</div>

      <div id="j2" class="ui-widget-content">Jogador 2</div>

      <div id="j3" class="ui-widget-content">Jogador 3</div>

      <div id="j4" class="ui-widget-content">Jogador 4</div>

      <div id="j5" class="ui-widget-content">Jogador 5</div>

      <div id="j6" class="ui-widget-content">Jogador 6</div>

      <div id="p1" class="ui-widget-header"><p>Posicao 1</p></div>

      <div id="p2" class="ui-widget-header"><p>Posicao 2</p></div>

      <div id="p3" class="ui-widget-header"><p>Posicao 3</p></div>

      <div id="p1" class="ui-widget-header"><p>Posicao 4</p></div>

      <div id="p2" class="ui-widget-header"><p>Posicao 5</p></div>

      <div id="p3" class="ui-widget-header"><p>Posicao 6</p></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please fill in the blanks `I want to see _____________ when I click on ________`

Comment: i want to see the id of the element dragged when i click on container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 3**: It doesn't look like there is a method to determine which "draggable" item is contained within the droppable. You will have to have a method to remember what was dropped into the container. The `data()` function on a jquery object is a good method for this.

In the drop function:

```
var itemId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
$(this).data('dropped', itemId);
```

In the click callback use:

```
if ($(item).data('dropped'))
{
    alert($(item).data('dropped'));
}
```

NOTE: This will only remember the most recently dropped item and will not remove it once it's dropped into a new container - that should be straightforward to implement.

**UPDATE 2**: The following should provide an alert with the id of the draggable item. I put the conditional in there to determine if it were moved into the container at the bottom.

```
$('.ui-widget-content').click(function (event) {
    var item = event.target;

    if (item.offsetTop >= 140)
    {
        alert(item.id);
    }
});
```

new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KLLCg/7/

**UPDATE**: It looks like you wanted something different. If you just want the ID of the destination container you should be able to get it using `event.target.id`

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    $(ui.draggable).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    $(ui.draggable).draggable('enable');

    var itemId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
    var destId = event.target.id ;
    var message = '"' + itemId + '" was dragged to "' + destId + '"';
    alert(message);
    console.log(message);
}
```

see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KLLCg/6/

ORIGINAL ANSWER

First - you should put your click handler inside the `document.ready`. I think you might be having a problem because the event target object will be whatever was clicked and the `<p>` element doesn't have an id. If I understand your problem the following code may work.

```
         $('.ui-widget-header').click(function (event) {
             var item = event.target;
             if (item.nodeName == 'P') {
                 item = item.parentNode;
             }
             alert(item.id);
         });
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/KLLCg/3/

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but this doesn't solve my problem, what i need is that when i click on the container it gives me the id of the element that was dragged inside

Comment: so when you drag the item to the container, after you release the mouse click, the alert shows the id of the item you dragged, not the item you released to?

Comment: when i drag the item to the container, after i release the mouse click it the alert that shows is correct, after that i want to click in the container and get the id again of that item that has been dropped there

Comment: OH! Ok, sorry about that. I think you need to add an onclick to the actual item then, I'll update the answer.

Comment: No is not that.. in your Update example of jsfiddle when you drag Jogador1 to the container Posicao1 that says "j1 was dragged to p1" and after that i want to click only in the container and get the same alert "j1 was dragged to p1". thanks once again for your time and patiente

Comment: still don't work, if you drag the item into the container and then click on the container still gives you de id "p1" that is the id of that container, but i want the id "j1" the id of the draggable tha is inside that container

Comment: Thank's caspian for all your knowledge about this. Thank's once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
You just have to store drag object id into "dragId".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<link href='../../css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<head>

    <style>

        .dragAndDrop
        {

        }

        .dragBoxStyle
        {
            position:absolute;
            left:170px;
            top:100px;

        }

        .dropBoxStyle
        {
            position:absolute;
            left:170px;
            top:300px;
        }

        .dragImageStyle
        {

        }

        .dropImageStyle
        {

        }

    </style>

    <script>

        var dragId;

        $(function()
        {
            $(".dragImageStyle").draggable();

            $(".dragImageStyle").mousedown(function()
            {
                dragId = (this.id);
            });


            $( ".dropImageStyle" ).droppable(
            {
                drop: function( event, ui ) 
                {
                    alert("Droped on "+this.id+" : "+dragId);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id = "dragAndDrop">

        <div id = "bg">
            <img src = "images/BG.jpg"></img>
        <div>

        <div id = "dropTiles" class = "dropBoxStyle">
            <img id = "drop1" class = "dropImageStyle" src = "images/Tab1_V.jpg"><img>
            <img id = "drop2" class = "dropImageStyle" src = "images/Tab2_V.jpg"><img>
            <img id = "drop3" class = "dropImageStyle" src = "images/Tab3_V.jpg"><img>
            <img id = "drop4" class = "dropImageStyle" src = "images/Tab4_V.jpg"><img>
        </div>  

        <div class = "dragBoxStyle">
            <img id = "dragBox1" src = "images/BlankBox.png"><img>
            <img id = "dragBox2" src = "images/BlankBox.png"><img>
            <img id = "dragBox3" src = "images/BlankBox.png"><img>
            <img id = "dragBox4" src = "images/BlankBox.png"><img>
        </div>

        <div id = "dragTiles" class = "dragBoxStyle">
            <img id = "drag1" class = "dragImageStyle" src = "images/Tab1_N.jpg"><img>
            <img id = "drag2" class = "dragImageStyle" src = "images/Tab2_N.jpg"><img>
            <img id = "drag3" class = "dragImageStyle" src = "images/Tab3_N.jpg"><img>
            <img id = "drag4" class = "dragImageStyle" src = "images/Tab4_N.jpg"><img>
        </div>          

    </div>
</body>
```